# downfile file through authentification

Tags: php, file, session, cookies, curl

I'm looking for a solution for this need. I have a website on www.mydomain.com. I would like to allow my visitors to download a file on www.otherdomain.com, using an cookie session based account user/password. Indeed, to download the file www.otherdomain.com/files/doc.pdf, it is required to be authenticated with user/password.

I have used cURL on my website to login on otherdomain.com, retrieve cookie and download the file, but it is not efficient as my webserver is downloading the file then send it to the client.

Moreover, I dont want my visitors to see the user/password :)

Do you have any idea to do this enhancement ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can chose between inefficiency and insecurity:

- Only if you fetch the doc (e.g. via cURL) does the end user **not** need any credentials for the other domain
- OTOH If you give the end user some sort of credentials, you lose control, what he does there.